# Compare two lists that contain a lot of objects (2th part)

Tags: c#, linq, performance, iequalitycomparer

Referring to the question that I previously asked:
[Compare two lists that contain a lot of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007892/compare-two-lists-that-contain-a-lot-of-objects)

It is impressive to see how fast that comparison is maide by implementing the IEqualityComparer interface: [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007892/compare-two-lists-that-contain-a-lot-of-objects/6007962#6007962)

As I mentioned in my other question this comparison helps me to backup a sourse folder on a destination folder. Know I want to sync to folders therefore I need to compare the dates of the files. Whenever I do something like:

```
public class MyFileComparer2 : IEqualityComparer<MyFile>
{

    public bool Equals(MyFile s, MyFile d)
    {
        return
            s.compareName.Equals(d.compareName) &&
            s.size == d.size &&
            s.deepness == d.deepness &&
            s.dateModified.Date <= d.dateModified.Date;  // This line does not work. 
            // I also tried comparing the strings by converting it to a string and it does
            // not work. It does not give me an error but it does not seem to include the files
            // where s.dateModified.Date < d.dateModified.Date

    }

    public int GetHashCode(MyFile a)
    {
        int rt = (a.compareName.GetHashCode() * 251 + a.size.GetHashCode() * 251 + a.deepness.GetHashCode() + a.dateModified.Date.GetHashCode());

        return rt;

    }
}
```

It will be nice if I could do something similar using greater or equal than signs. I also tried using the tick property and it does not work. Maybe I am doing something wrong. I believe it is not possible to compare things with the less than equal sign implementing this interface. Moreover, I don't understand how this Class works; I just know it is impressive how fast it iterates through the whole list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the DateTime objects are different in the case when one DateTime is less than the other, you get different hashcodes for the objects *s* and *d* and the Equals method is not called. In order for your comparison of the dates to work, you should remove the date part from the GetHashCode method:

```
public int GetHashCode(MyFile a)
{
    int rt = ((a.compareName.GetHashCode() * 251 + a.size.GetHashCode())
                          * 251 + a.deepness.GetHashCode()) *251;

    return rt;

}
```

Comment: Because `Equals` is not reflexive, this can never work, even with a fixed `GetHashCode`.

Answer (score 4):

Your whole approach is fundementally flawed because your `IEqualityComparer.Equals` method is not symmetric.  This means `Equals(file1, file2)` does not equal `Equals(file2, file1)`  because of the way you are using the less than operator.

The documentation:

- [IEqualityComparer.Equals Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.iequalitycomparer.equals.aspx)

clearly states:

> **Notes to Implementers**
>
> The Equals method is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive. That is, it returns true if used to compare an object with itself; true for two objects x and y if it is true for y and x; and true for two objects x and z if it is true for x and y and also true for y and z.
>
> Implementations are required to ensure that if the Equals method returns true for two objects x and y, then the value returned by the GetHashCode method for x must equal the value returned for y.

Instead you need to use the `IComparable` interface or `IEqualityComparer` in combination with date comparisions.  If you do not, things might seem to work for a while but you will regret it later.

Answer (score 0):

Your GetHashCode has a problem:

```
public int GetHashCode(MyFile a)
{
    int rt = (((a.compareName.GetHashCode() * 251) 
           + a.size.GetHashCode() * 251)
           + a.deepness.GetHashCode() *251) 
           + a.dateModified.Date.GetHashCode();

    return rt;

}
```

Comment: What's the problem?  Spell it out.  And while you're at it note that hashing the date is probably not such a great idea if it is not part of the definition of equality.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the date part because I also needed the time therefore I use the ticks property instead. I got rid of the dateModified hashed code and it works great. here is how I modified my program. I was having trouble comparing the dates therefore I used the Ticks property.

```
public class MyFileComparer2 : IEqualityComparer<MyFile>
{

    public bool Equals(MyFile s, MyFile d)
    {
        return
            s.compareName.Equals(d.compareName) &&
            s.size == d.size &&
            s.deepness == d.deepness &&
            //s.dateModified.Date <= d.dateModified.Date &&
            s.dateModified.Ticks >= d.dateModified.Ticks
            ;  

    }

    public int GetHashCode(MyFile a)
    {
        int rt = (((a.compareName.GetHashCode() * 251)
                + a.size.GetHashCode() * 251)
                + a.deepness.GetHashCode() * 251)
                //+ a.dateModified.Ticks.GetHashCode();                       
                ;

        return rt;

    }
}
```

I still don't know how this hash code function works. The nice thing is that it works great.